# ssrs calculate share % devide by total of column

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a matrix in ssrs:

```
CustName     MonthSales     Share %
ABC          1000           50%
DEF          500            25%
GHI          500            25%
Total        2000           100%
```

So CustName is a row group.  I'm trying to calculate the Share % as follows:

```
=Fields!MonthSales.Value / 
sum(Fields!MonthSales.Value, "CustName")
```

**but I keep getting 100%**

Answer (score 0):

I should have taken the DataSet scope:

```
=Fields!MonthSales.Value / 
sum(Fields!MonthSales.Value, "DataSet1")
```